# Randomly pick one item from an array and then delete

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values.

```
 array =  ["A", "B", "C"];
```

I want to randomly select an item, do something with it, then remove it from the array. Go back and get another item, etc.. etc..

So that I get:

```
$item = "B";
array = ["A","C"]; 
$item = "C";
array = ["A"]; 
$item = "A";
array =[];
```

I know Ruby has a `array.delete_at()` function which would work great if i was using Ruby. Is there a function similar to that in just generic PHP?

Comment: Why do you want to delete items one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomize with `shuffle()` and then pop one off the end, or shift off of the beginning with `array_shift()`, doesn't matter:

```
shuffle($array);  // you only need to do this once
$item = array_pop($array);
```

Similar to the Ruby you show would be to get a random key and use it to get the value, then use it to `unset()` that element:

```
$item = $array[$key=array_rand($array)];
unset($array[$key]);
```

Comment: Quick and painless. Right on!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible answers:

If you don't care about order of elements that will be left in the array, for example you will pick all elements anyway:

```
$array =  ["A", "B", "C"];

shuffle($array);
while (!empty($array)) {
    $randomElement = array_pop($array);
    var_dump($randomElement);
}
```

If you don't want to pick all element, only few. You can remove just elements that you pick, leaving other in the same order:

```
 $array =  ["A", "B", "C"];

 while (!empty($array)) {
     $randomKey = array_rand($array);
     $randomElement = $array[$randomKey];
     unset($array[$randomKey]);
     var_dump($randomElement);
 }
```

Comment: There's no need to shuffle the array inside the loop. Do it before the loop once and for all.

Comment: Even though I selected the other answer, you should leave yours just in case someone else needs a method similar to your solution.